# Overwrite Category Display Mode from "Static Content Only" to "Products Only" via Layout XML

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I want to overwrite the "Display Mode" backend setting of a certain category via layout xml file (e.g. catalog_category_view_id_XYZ.xml).

Any idea how to update the layout handle?

I want to do this via layout xml file, so I can populate the category during a certain period of time (christmas offers should only be seen during december) with a scheduled child theme and the rest of the year there should only be the static block.

Cheers,
Juha

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can set this in Layout XML, and even if you can the admin value usually overwrites anything set in Layout XML.

You can also schedule the display mode, so set the from and to date and change the display mode.

[image]

Comment: Agree with @Ben, +1 for your answer :)

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. unfortunately this feature is not present in magento2.1.5

Comment: Are you using the community/open-source/free edition? I believe scheduling is only in the commerce/enterprise edition. If this is the case I'm not aware of a way you can achieve this, maybe there are plugins that can help.